# Automatically run junit tests after build in NetBeans 8.0.1

Tags: java, netbeans, junit4

I have a simple question. Is there a way to configure NetBeans so that after build JUnit tests in test package would run automatically ? I'm using NetBeans 8.0.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Infinitest is such a project, but it seems that its support for Netbeans is minor if not nonexistent.  But that would give you a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Maven there's an option under Tools / Options / Java / Maven / Execution / Skip Tests for any build executions not directly related  to testing. Make sure that this one is unchecked.

If you are using Ant this is also possible. It's been some years since I used Ant but from top of my head you need to modify your build.xml. There needs to be a target like "compile" and there you add in the depends-property the targetname for the unit tests.

Comment: Thanks. Just interesting what I need to add exactly. If I add in depends list `compile-test` I get error _Circular dependency: compile <- compile-test <- compile_. If I add just `test` to depends list - I get similar error of circular dependency _compile <- compile-test <- test <- compile_

Answer (score 0):

For a project specific solution:
Right-click on your project -> Properties -> Actions.

Select "Build project" ("Debug project" and "Run project" work too!"
Add "surefire:test " at the beginning of the Execute Goals.

If you now share your source code with others, they will automatically run your tests too!

Comment: I know this thread is old, but it was high on google search rankings for me, so I felt it was worth adding.